# Differences between using sql IN() with subselect and code-generated string

Tags: java, sql

Imagine we have an sql such as
SELECT something FROM TableName WHERE something NOT IN (SELECT ...);
And result size of second SELECT is a huge.
So what if I change second SELECT by generated string value such as
"a1, a2, a3, ... an", where is n - is a really big number. Will I get an error that  sql query size is too large? Is this size limited? Is this size different for result of second SELECT and generated string?

Comment: It will mostly depend on the database you use and not the JVM.

Comment: Without a database tag, this question is too broad.  There are lots and lots of databases and application interfaces to them.

Comment: Database - clickhouse

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on your database engine/server. You can play with database specific settings to overcome (or) at least extend some of these limits.

But overall I think you should look for solutions liks "Join" instead of subqueries. There are [some advantages with that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query).